# Classification of isometries of a regular polygon

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A dihedral group is the group of symmetries of a regular polygon, including both rotations and reflections. Here comes my **question**:

> How can I show that rotations and reflections are the **only** symmetries of a regular polygon?

I have found no proof for such a statement when the dihedral groups are introduced in lots of textbooks. It might be a starting point to show first that an isometry (symmetry) on a regular polygon maps the vertices to vertices and then the center must be a fixed point of the isometry. But I get stuck with showing that reflections are the only possible isometries besides the rotations.

Comment: I read @Günter Rote's answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3424269/249653: how can you formally show that a symmetry maps a vertex to a vertex?

Answer (score 1):

A symmetry must map vertex 1 to some vertex $i$. Vertex 2 must be mapped to an ajacent vertex, $i+1$ or $i-1$. Once you know the images of 1 and 2, the other vertices are fixed.
If 2 is mapped to $i+1$ you have the rotations. If 2 is mapped to $i-1$, you have the reflections (This might require some more arguments, at the elementary level at which this question is posed.)

Comment: How can you formally show that a symmetry maps a vertex to a vertex?

Comment: @Paolo, as you ask for *formal* proof, you have to first *formally* state what you mean by symmetry, and by vertex.
Informally: if you see a polygon you can see where the vertices are. A symmetry maps the polygon to itself, so a vertex cannot move to a place where there was no vertex.

Answer (score 0):

An isometry must fix the center of a polygon (thought of as a solid polygon) and so the only isometries of the plane which could induce a symmetry of the polygon are reflections, and rotations. (This assumes that we know the isometries of the plane are generated by translations, and reflections across lines through the origin)

Comment: So one might also need to show that the isometries of a regular polygon must be induced from those of the plane?

Comment: I suppose that needs to be proved, but I imagine it follows rather easily from the fact that isometries of the circle extend to isometries of the disk, extend to isometries of the plane.