# Understanding the Dihedral group, $D_n$

Tags: group-theory, dihedral-groups

I know what the dihedral group is, the group of symmetries (length-preserving) functions of a regular n-gon.
However, when it is referring to the symmetries of the regular n-gon what is it referring to?
Is it referring to the symmetries of:
The set of vertices on the n-gon, the set of points in the n-gon or the set of points on the edges of the n-gon ?

Also is it considering these points as points in the complex plane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we are talking about isometries from the one-dimensional figure (the union of the edges of the $n$-gon)  into itself. Of course, the restriction of such an isometry to the vertices of the $n$-gon will also be an isometry and every isometry from the set of the vertices of the $n$-gon into itself can be extended to one and only one isometry from the one-dimensional figure into itself.

Comment: Ok. So if I wish to define a group action which rotates an nxn grid of squares then I cannot use the $<r>$ subgroup of $D_4$ as this only acts on the outline of the grid and not on the interior squares?

Comment: I don't really see a deep difference betw those concepts, since any isometry of the grid extends to one and only one isometry of the wholo region and every isometry of the whole regin restricted to the grid is an isometry of the grid.

Comment: By isometry do you mean permutation?

Comment: Not at all. I mean length-preserving.

Comment: Ok. In my notes it calls these functions “symmetries”. I assume this is synonymous with “isometry”

Comment: In this context, yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

All points of the polygon (interior and boundary) are defined by the vertices.  So a symmetry of the polygon is a permutation of the vertices.

But not every permutation of the vertices is a symmetry of the polygon.  For instance, swapping two adjacent vertices of a square isn't a symmetry of the square.

Comment: Why must vertices be mapped by a symmetry into other vertices?

Comment: I'd have to research the actual proof (I'd try to use the [Mazur-Ulam theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem)), but basically, the vertices are characterized using properties of distance; an isometry of the polygon preserves distances; therefore, an isometry of the polygon maps vertices to vertices.  Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482588/classification-of-isometries-of-a-regular-polygon

Comment: Thank you that makes sense.